# nginx proxy all traffic to remote nginx

Tags: proxy, nginx, traffic

I have 2 servers,

1. with IP xx.xx.xx.xx, situated in Germany ... (running frontend: nginx(static content), backend: Apache2)
2. with IP yy.yy.yy.yy, situated in Italy...

All requests at the moment is sending to server with IP xx.xx.xx.xx,
**How can I proxy all traffic from xx.xx.xx.xx to yy.yy.yy.yy using nginx ...**

```
          request                           proxy, request
Internet     ->       xx.xx.xx.xx(nginx)         ->             yy.yy.yy.yy(nginx, Apache)
             <-                                  <-
          response                          proxy, response
```

Comment: Did you try read documentation? proxy_pass _http://yy.yy.yy.yy

Comment: sure! but how to read the X-Real-IP on remote side(ip: yy.yy.yy.yy) ??

Comment: All of the solutions did not work for me. I went with the (closed source) [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/).

Answer (score 126):

For others. Answer for subject is configure Nginx like:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name mydomain.example;
    location / {
      access_log off;
      proxy_pass http://mydomain.example:8080;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `location /` match all paths? or only the root path '\'?

Comment: @pomo according guidlines here http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location it will match all nested queries such as site.com/index.html but not for root  query aka site.com/

Comment: @VladimirShmidt it matches root location too.

Comment: This works great! Is pretty much the same as when setting up a private node server and using nginx as the public server.

Comment: What about Authentication in upstream proxy for example  server : http://mydomain.example:8080  user : xxxx pass : yyyy ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use upsteream like:

```
upstream  xx.xx.xx.xx:8080{
    #ip_hash;
    server xx.xx.xx.xx:8080 max_fails=2  fail_timeout=2s;
    server yy.yy.yy.yy:8181 max_fails=2  fail_timeout=2s;
}
```

then you can use the cookie or header to set the request like:

```
location /app {
        if ($cookie_proxy_override = "proxy-target-A") {
            rewrite . http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/app;
            proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            break;
        }
        if ($cookie_proxy_override = "proxy-target-B") {
            rewrite . http://yy.yy.yy.yy:8181/webreg;
            proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            break;
        }
        proxy_pass http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/webreg;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
```

Comment: This is wrong syntax and it won't work. You should set any name to upstream, like `upstream myservers { ... }` and then you can use this name in `proxy_pass http://myservers;`